# wrap_content does not work with custom RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I have created a custom layout which extends `RelativeLayout`. At the moment, this layout does nothing except overriding the `onMeasure` method (that I will need later). Here is my code:

```
public class CustomLayout extends RelativeLayout {

    public CustomLayout(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

And I have the following layout file:

```
   <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/containerLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:baselineAligned="false"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <...CustomLayout
            android:id="@+id/item"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#fff" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Hello"
                android:textSize="20sp" />

        </...CustomLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/controls"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="50"
            android:background="#0f0" >
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

The problem is that the height is null. During my debugging, I have noticed that if I change the `CustomLayout` to a `RelativeLayout` it works.

So, it is quite obvious that the problem comes from my `CustomLayout`, but what do I need to add to make the `wrap_content` work ?

Comment: Try to set height to match_parent and let me know what happens ?

Comment: It is the same, the height is null. And, again, if I use a `RelativeLayout` with `match_parent` it works.

Comment: Why you do call  setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec); and overrides results from super.onMeasure() ?

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed that. I was answering my question when I saw your comment. Anyway, thank you for your help ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally found the problem. I change this:

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
     setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
 }
```

To this:

```
 @Override
 protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
     super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
 }
```

And it works fine.

**Explanation**

First, the following line was useless:

```
setMeasuredDimension(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
```

But why does it makes the `View`'s height null?

In fact, I misunderstood the paramaters of the `onMeasure` method. They are `MeasureSpec` values. Here is what Google says about this object:

> A MeasureSpec encapsulates the layout requirements passed from parent
>   to child. Each MeasureSpec represents a requirement for either the
>   width or the height. A MeasureSpec is comprised of a size and a mode.
>   There are three possible modes:
>
> UNSPECIFIED The parent has not imposed any constraint on the child. It
>   can be whatever size it wants. EXACTLY The parent has determined an
>   exact size for the child. The child is going to be given those bounds
>   regardless of how big it wants to be. AT_MOST The child can be as
>   large as it wants up to the specified size. MeasureSpecs are
>   implemented as ints to reduce object allocation. This class is
>   provided to pack and unpack the  tuple into the int

The `widthMeasureSpec` and `heightMeasureSpec` values are not only the width and the height of the `View`. In this case, passing these values to `setMeasureDimension` are completly wrong because this method actually requires *real* sizes as parameters.